# How to create a layout for a higher DPI than xxxhdpi?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I've got a Pixel XL and I like to keep the screen size set to `small`. However, the default size for the Pixel is defined by Google as `xxxhdpi`, so my increasing the dpi isn't "detected" so no scaling is triggered.

When making an app, I can't seem to create a folder called `xxxxhdpi` or `xxlarge`, so I'm kind of at a loss as to how to define the layout for the higher DPI.

I found a resource suggesting to simply define the dpi, i.e. calling the folder `720dpi`, but Android Studio throws a compile error if I do that.

Does anyone have any idea how I can make the app show up correctly on my phone?

Comment: define them by minimum width instead. As long as you use `dp` and `sp` instead of `px` you don't need to make layouts to handle every single density

Comment: `a higher DPI than xxxhdpi?` AFAIK, **there's nothing** beyond xxxhdpi. No android device screen has a higher **density** than xxxhdpi, currently.

Comment: `I found a resource suggesting to simply define the dpi, i.e. calling the folder "720dpi"` **Never** heard about such a resource folder. You probably mean `sw720dp`

Comment: @Zoe the minimum width is the same I believe, since the resolution is technically the same, only the DPI changes.

Comment: @NoiseGenerator this website defines it as _nnn_ dpi https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

And of course there is higher DPI than `xxxhdpi`, since `xxxhdpi` is the default DPI of the Pixel XL, and I'm running a higher DPI.

Comment: @eydryan no, minimum width in dp of a device isn't necessarily the same as the global screen density. A device can be 720 dp wide, but have 320 dpi in resolution

Comment: `dpi` defines **density**, not **resolution**. It's a *common beginners mistake*, to confuse density with resolution.

Comment: How about you describe what is your actual problem? instead of what you are trying to do, maybe then we can suggest an alternative that will work

Comment: @elmorabea I run my Pixel XL at a higher DPI than stock. I have made an app that can benefit from a higher DPI but I find no way to define a layout for a regular Pixel XL DPI (xxxhdpi) and also another layout for my, higher, DPI. Feel free to have a look at the github, as well as my "xxxxhdpi" branch: https://github.com/adriantache/Super-Tic-Tac-Toe

Comment: What do you mean by higher DPI? How can the device DPI change?

Comment: @elmorabea you can go into the settings, and select a display "size" smaller than default, which increases the effective dpi of the device. It should just be scaling, but it works like a dpi change, messing with layouts.

Comment: Are you talking about font size settings?

Comment: @elmorabea No. Go into Display settings on your device, and _under_ `Font size` you have an option called `Display size`.

Answer (score -1):

Can you make minmap-xlarge resource folder?  but not sure whether Pixel xl device will read from it. Here is the screenshot.[image]